# Populate Solr Managed Schema deletes added solr fields

Tags: solr

I am adding fields via the Solr admin and can see them in the managed-schema file, however when I go to Sitecore Populate Solr Managed Schema, and run it, those fields get removed

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you're not on Sitecore 9.3 then yes, known issue.

Comment: 9.1, actually. So this is a bug rather than a "feature"?

Comment: Yes - work around is not to use populate solr managed schema after you manually modify the schema.xml. But perhaps contact support they might patch it properly.